# Usage of super() in Multiple and Multilevel inheritance

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, inheritance, multiple-inheritance

I am new to multiple and multilevel inheritance. I was trying to execute an example:

```
class First(object):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        print("first")

class Second(object):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        print("second")

class Third(First, Second):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        print("third")
Third()
```

The output I got is:

```
second
first
third
<__main__.Third at 0x21bbaf2fc88>
```

Could anyone please explain me the reason for this output?
I was expecting the output to be:

```
first
second
third
```

As __init__() of third would call __init__() of First class (because it is first in the parent list) which would print first then second class's __init__() and then finally __init__() of third class.

MRO  prints what I expected.

```
print(Third.__mro__)
```

prints

```
(__main__.Third, __main__.First, __main__.Second, object)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you do `super().__init__()` *before* you call `print(xxx)`,the order shown is right.

If you want the order showed in the "excepted" tab, you can swap each `print(xxx)` with `super().__init__()`,and that will fix it.

Code:

```
class First(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print("first")
        super().__init__()

class Second(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print("second")
        super().__init__()

class Third(First, Second):
    def __init__(self):
        print("third")            
        super().__init__()
Third()
```

Comment: How do you justify the order if I have print after super. Any how ```super().__init__()``` isn't doing anything in case of Class First and Second

Comment: First answer: It's the same as justfiying the order of printing in recurcion.
Second answer: `super()` doesn't mean your parent class,it means next in the MRO list,this is why `super()` in `First` calls to `Second.__init__` and not `object.__init__`

Answer (score 1):

This seems to just be an artifact of when you're printing in `__init__`. Your current code prints *after* it calls `super().__init__`, and so the inheritance hierarchy prints out in reverse order. If you print before the super call, it will be in the same order as the MRO. Perhaps it would be easiest to understand if you printed both ways:

```
class First(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print("first (top)")
        super().__init__()
        print("first (bottom)")

class Second(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print("second (top)")
        super().__init__()
        print("second (bottom)")

class Third(First, Second):
    def __init__(self):
        print("third (top)")
        super().__init__()
        print("third (bottom)")
```

Now the output of `Third()` should be:

```
third (top)
first (top)
second (top)
second (bottom)
first (bottom)
third (bottom)
```

The output you see that is `<__main__.Third ...>` isn't being printed by any of your code, but by the interactive shell. It's the *result* of calling `Third`, an instance of the class. If you did `instance = Third()`, you wouldn't see that, as the value would be stored to the variable, and not printed out. The REPL (Read Eval Print Loop) only runs when Python is runnig interactively, it won't do any extra printing in modules you import or run as a script.

Comment: Shouldn't first (bottom) be printed after first (top). And what do you mean by artifact?

Comment: No, all the calls are nested. `Third.__init__` calls `First.__init__`, which calls `Second.__init__` (which calls `object.__init__`, which does nothing). `super()` means "next on the MRO", not "all my parent classes". That's why you get the `First`->`Second` call, rather than `First` calling to `object` the way it would do for a different instance.

Comment: ```Third.__init__``` calls ```First.__init__``` which calls ```object.__init__``` which does nothing. ```First.__init__```  doesn't call ```Second.__init__``` as you mentioned.

Comment: No, I had it right. And it's why you get the printouts in the order I show (I tested it by running the code, this isn't just theory). Python's `super` really is Super. It does special stuff in the case of multiple inheritance so that two base classes that don't know about each other can still collaborate. In this case, it's `First.__init__` calling `super().__init__()`, which for a `Third` instance will mean calling `Second.__init__` next. That's very weird, but useful! If you created a `First` instance directly, it wouldn't do that, it would, as you say, jump straight to `object.__init__`.